# How do I make 'org-beginning-of-line' move cursor to the first text in heading body

Tags: org-mode

For example in a org file (cursor represented as `|`):

```
* heading
    this is body |of the heading
    1. some
    2. list
```

After 'org-beginning-of-line' :

```
* heading
    |this is body of the heading
    1. some
    2. list
```

Is there a good way to do this **without losing org-mode syntax awareness**  `org-beginning-of-line` provided ?

Comment: See: http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/05/22/smarter-navigation-to-the-beginning-of-a-line/

Comment: Specifically for org-mode I don't see any value in manually indenting like you seem to do.  I suggest you try using org-mode with this setting: `(setq org-startup-indented t)`.

Comment: @mankoff, I am talking about an implementation that will work well with org-mode, not just ignore all org mode syntax.

Comment: @paprika I did not manually indent the text like that, just FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility would be to add an advice to `org-beginning-of-line`

```
(defadvice org-beginning-of-line (around ad-org-beginning-of-line-around act)
  "Move back to indentation first, then to beginning of line"
  (let ((initial-position (point)))
    ad-do-it
    (when (looking-at "^ +")
      (when (equal initial-position
                   (progn (back-to-indentation)
                          (point)))
        (beginning-of-line)))))
```

But really, the only advantage of doing that is to keep using `C-a` (which behaves differently on headers and items). Ideally, it would probably be better to start using the "proper" binding for `back-to-indentation` directly: `M-m`

Comment: Your `advice` does work, but it also make `org-beginning-of-line` not able to move to the first character of the line.

Comment: I already use `back-to-indentation`. But I use `C-a` in other mode with implementation like @kaushalmodi's answer. Just wondering whether I can make `C-a` works like I do in other mode.

Comment: @RangiLin I edited my code so that hitting `C-a` repeatedly would toggle between beginning of line and indentation position.

Comment: Ah, nice, I didn't think of that :), it works pretty well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have bound <kbd>C-a</kbd> to the `back-to-indentation-or-beginning-of-line` function below that I got from @lunaryorn's [`init.el`](https://github.com/lunaryorn/stante-pede/blob/master/init.el). *I recommend having a look at that init.el for more useful snippets like this.*

```
;; Make C-a toggle between beginning of line and indentation
;; https://github.com/lunaryorn/stante-pede/blob/master/init.el
(defun back-to-indentation-or-beginning-of-line (arg)
  "Move point back to indentation of beginning of line.
Move point to the first non-whitespace character on this line.
If point is already there, move to the beginning of the line.
Effectively toggle between the first non-whitespace character and
the beginning of the line.
If ARG is not nil or 1, move forward ARG - 1 lines first.  If
point reaches the beginning or end of the buffer, stop there."
  (interactive "^p")
  (setq arg (or arg 1))

  ;; Move lines first
  (when (/= arg 1)
    (let ((line-move-visual nil))
      (forward-line (1- arg))))

  (let ((orig-point (point)))
    (back-to-indentation)
    (when (= orig-point (point))
      (move-beginning-of-line 1))))
```

I have bound this to my minor mode key map so that it can override the `C-a` bindings of all other modes (including `org-mode`).

Comment: This implementation does not aware of org mode syntax, which is why I prefer use `org-beginning-of-line` in org mode.